# what is the maximum size of an ethereum transaction?

Tags: go-ethereum

I want ot know what is the maximum size of an ethereum transaction ?

I have a DAPP that makes a 1Milion transactions per year, I want to describe the deployment requirements such as Storage, RAM etc ..

Comment: But since [this commit](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/commit/eebde1a2e202e92eee722ff0841cda4bd0257a62) release with geth v1.6.6 it will drop transactions over 32kb.

Answer (score 0):

The transactions are only limited by the amount of gas that they require to be processed, the limit is then the block gas limit which currently is 8000000 gas.

The contract deployment is itself a transaction and therefore has the same limitations or any other transaction.

The RAM requirements of your dApp are not related to ethereum network in any way, notice that you do not need to store the transaction locally as these are in the network and you can access it anytime.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The Dapp is private, and I will setup a private network (PoA) , to deploy every ethereum node I have to define hardware & software requirements, proccessing a large number of transactions depends on CPU and RAM so it's important to define everything before starting

Comment: In POA networks you can define the block gas limit and block time that you want, calculate your average transaction cost, multiply it by 1M, and you get the total gas you will need, depending on your latency between nodes, or CPU power decide block time and block gas limit, once you are done, you need to define which node you will be using, and look if they can meet your spec, afterwards, calculate the space of the state tree you will have after a year and you can estimate your disk requirements, as for ram, really depends on the node

Comment: why mutiplying by 1M ?  I think 1M is the maximum size of a block.  The only informations I have is the number of transactions per day and the average size of a transaction.

Comment: @Enrique, that sounds like a good answer, please make your comment an answer as it fits better what the OP is asking for.